# python system to dynamically load variables and modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic, module

i am trying to build an infrastructure which uses a text file to dynamically setup an environment in which code should run. the text file will contain paths of python modules to load AND variables which other parts of my code will need.  thus, i am trying to use one mechanism for loading modules and variables (versus virtualenv just for modules and another scheme for variables)

my code would look like:

my_script_which_uses_env.py:

```
import envcontrol_module
import some_other_module_whose_path_is_unknown_at_run_time

def main():
     my_envcontrol = envcontrol_module.EnvControlClass()
     my_variable = my_envcontrol.get_value("SOME_VARIABLE")
```

those using my infrastructure would be required to "import envcontrol_module" as the first line in their code.  after that import is done, then the syspath has already been modified to include the paths of the modules to load, ie when import envcontrol_module returns, the sys path has the path for some_other_module_whose_path_is_unknown_at_run_time.

at a high level, i think the following is needed:
1. need "import envcontrol_module" to cause a reading of my config text file.  this would create a dict with the variable names and values. here i could modify sys.path
2. somehow keep this dict around such that when an instance of EnvControlClass is created, this class is able to access the dict

envcontrol_module.py

```
def main():
    config_dict = read_config_file()
    modify_sys_path(config_dict)

class EnvControl():
    self.config_dict = config_dict
```

how can i do the above in a python friendly way:
1. config dict is not global to envcontrol_module
2. maintain the need for this to be transparent to programmers, they simply do "import envcontrol_module" first and then do subsequent imports normally

i know i can do the following, but then the programmers would do the imports in their main() rather than at top of file, which will be different/not as nice/not python-esque:

my_script_which_uses_env.py:

```
import envcontrol_module

def main():
    my_envcontrol = envcontrol_module.EnvControlClass()
    import some_other_module_whose_path_is_unknown_at_run_time
    my_variable = my_envcontrol.get_value("SOME_VARIABLE")
```

envcontrol_module.py

```
class EnvControl():
    def __init__(self):
    self.config_dict = read_config_file()
    modify_sys_path(config_dict)
```

not sure if i explained this well.  if i haven't, let me know and i can clarify more.

thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of `EnvControlClass`?

Comment: @Blender so that i can access other variables needed.  the config file will contain python module paths and other variables which affect code execution.  i need a way to access those variables after the paths have been modified.

Comment: From what I understand, there's a single config file and you globally modify `sys.path`. Are you going to create multiple instances of `EnvControlClass`?

Comment: @Blender yes, that's correct...globally modify sys.path.  the config file reading system will be a bit more elaborate, but yes you can think of it as a single file.  during execution time, EnvControlClass will be used to access those vars.  it will also be possible to set/modify vars during execution time, ie EnvControlClass.set_value() methods are needed.  typically only one EnvControlClass is needed during execution, but there is one use case where i could instantiate multiple (for example, i create one instance based on configA and another on configB to do a config file comparison)

Comment: Can you explain the issue with keeping `config_dict` as a global?

Comment: @Blender i'm trying to avoid global vars in files.  also, i think it would limit me from doing that configA to configB comparison i mentioned.

Comment: But you would need to know the contents of config A and config B in order to patch `sys.path` with the appropriate paths when `envcontrol_module` is imported, would you not? I think you need to make a more concrete example because I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this module.